# How do I redirect users after submitting a replies for moderation on bbpress?

Tags: redirect, bbpress, moderation

After a user submits a new reply for moderation, the forum shows up again the same page, and with no explanation that the reply is awaiting moderation. Can I redirect the user to another URL with an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the serious flaws in bbpress, and surprisingly nobody at bbpress is interested to solve this.

One work around is to download the plugin "404 solution", after activation go to "Add Redirect", then "Manual Redirect", add the following as the main URL of bbpress:

```
https://www.example.com/?post_type=topic&p=xxxx.
```

Change your domain with your website link, and remove the xxxx, because that will be your new topic ID and will be different for every new topic.

Next, add the page URL in the redirection box, where you would want the redirection to land.

But before completing the action make sure to check the box which says:
Treat this URL as a regular expression *Explain*

Read and confirm the warning message while doing this.

That's all, now you can press the "Add Redirect" button your problem will be hopefully solved